# Dragging disables itself after a while on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This has been an issue for me for several projects now. It always happens after I spend some time away from the window in question, while I'm in my IDE for instance. I noticed that coming back to the window with my JavaScript project all forms of drag and drop were unresponsive. This has been the case with jQuery UI's drag-n-drop, Fabric.js' and Create.js' canvas dragging and even things I've written on my own.

Couldn't find the issue being reported elsewhere, is this something that occurs often? Is it something from my chrome settings?

Comment: It is probably related to your chrome installation or a problem with your computer, maybe try to reproduce this on another one

Comment: It actually has happened on my collegues computers, while we were working on a project that has draggable windows, made with jQuery.